# Djangoとdjango-social-authでのurlsの書き方について

Tags: python, django, api, facebook-api

Django1.6にてdjango-social-authを使用しております。

ログインは、

settings.pyにはAPP_NAMEを自分のアプリ名で定義し、

```
LOGIN_URL = APP_NAME + '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = APP_NAME + '/login-error/'
```

urls.spyに

```
url(r'^login/$', 'social_auth.views.auth',
    {'backend': 'facebook'}, name='login'),
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
```

のように記載することで、ログインは出来ました。

しかし、ログインのキャンセル時に/login-error/に対するurlが存在しないようなエラーとなってしまいます。
しかし、/login-error/に対応する記述方法が見つかりません。

どのように記述したらよろしいでしょうか？

また、Faceook認証だけでなくGoogle＋認証もしたいのですが、

```
{'backend': ['facebook', google]}, name='login'),
```

みたいなことも記載できず、backendに対してどのように記載するのかが不明です。

ご教示お願い致します。